# Javascript objection creation with function contructor

Tags: javascript, closures

I was expecting the obj to be instanceof F1 ('this' in 'this.prop' refers to F1 object in the code snippet below, similarly I thought 'this' in 'return this' of C1 refers to F1 which is not the case. It refers to Global Window object), but in actuality it is an instanceof Window. Why is that ? could you please explain ?

```
function F1() {
  this.prop = 5;
  function C1() {
   return this;
  }
  return C1();
}
var obj = new F1();
```

Comment: Have a look at [what MDN says about `this`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this). Basically `this` is set depending on how a function is called, and the `this` inside `C1()` is definitely not supposed to be the same object as in `new F1()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you are just creating an instance of `F1`, then just do this:

```
function F1() {
  this.prop = 5;
}
var obj = new F1();
```

you don't need to return anything.

---

the `this` inside `C1` is not the same as `this` outside it. if you want to preserve `this` of the outside so that `C1` can use it, store it into another variable

```
function F1() {

    //preserve "this" from outside 
    var that = this;

    this.prop = 5;

    function C1() {
       return that; //"that" is "this" of the outside
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, But I am wondering how the this in C1 refers to the Global Object Window when C1 is a private function of F1, isn't it ?. It is a little difficult to comprehend for me

Comment: it's explained in [nnnnnn's comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10255547/javascript-objection-creation-with-function-contructor/10255586#comment13184216_10255547) especially in the [Function context](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this#Function_context) section. It was one of JavaScript's flaws where an inner function had access to the global object.